# False Proof that $\sqrt{4}$ is Irrational

Tags: proof-verification

Everyone with any basic knowledge of number theory knows the classic proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$. Curious about generalizations using elementary methods,  I looked up the irrationality of $\sqrt{3}$, and found the following:

> Say $ \sqrt{3} $ is rational. Then $\sqrt{3}$ can be represented as $\frac{a}{b}$, where a and b have **no common factors**.
>
> So $3 = \frac{a^2}{b^2}$ and $3b^2 = a^2$. Now $a^2$ must be divisible by $3$, but then so must $a $ (fundamental theorem of arithmetic). So we have $3b^2 = (3k)^2$ and $3b^2 = 9k^2$ or even $b^2 = 3k^2 $ and now we have a contradiction.

Such a proof follows the same basic logic as the proof for $\sqrt{2}$, except for using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic to replace and generalize the trivial fact that $n$ is even if $n^2$ is even.  However,  when I apply this proof format to $\sqrt{4} $ (which is clearly an integer and thus rational)  I get the following:

Say $ \sqrt{4} $ is rational. Then $\sqrt{4}$ can be represented as $\frac{a}{b}$, where a and b have **no common factors**.

So $4 = \frac{a^2}{b^2}$ and $4b^2 = a^2$. Now $a^2$ must be divisible by $4$, but then so must $a $ (fundamental theorem of arithmetic). So we have $4b^2 = (4k)^2$ and $4b^2 = 16k^2$ or even $b^2 = 4k^2 $, which implies that $b=4n$ by the fundamental theorem. Now we have a contradiction (since can note that both $a$ and $b$ are divisible by $4$ and we assumed they were coprime)

This proof is **clearly** false,  yet I fail to see where it differs. Where does it do so?

Comment: Whereas $2$ and $3$ are primes, $4$ is not a prime.  So the claim that $4 \mid a^2$ (i.e. $4$ divides $a^2$) does not imply $4 \mid a$.  As a counterexample, $4$ divides $a^2 = 36$, but $4$ does not divide $a = 6$.

Comment: Perhaps more obviously (if we were to take the obvious approach and set $a=2$, $b=1$), $4$ divides $2^2$ but does not divide $2$.

Comment: The essential property here that $2$ and $3$ possess but $4$ does not is *squarefreeness*: ihey are composed of distinct prime factors.  If $d$ is divisible by any prime squared then it is false that "$d$ divides $a^2$" implies "$d$ divides $a$".

Comment: Note regarding above comments: primality and squarefreeness are not sufficient and necessary conditions; not being a perfect square is. The argument that the square root of an integer is irrational applies to any non-perfect square, whether composite or containing a nontrivial square factor.

Comment: There is a foolproof method of finding at what step a false proof like this fails, which is indicated in Fimpellizieri's comment: you substitute what you know to be a counterexample to the final result, and see at what point you've written down a false statement about your counterexample. You can always do this; it requires essentially no cleverness.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret Our comments could be misconstrued so let me clarify.  It's true that the square root of a non-perfect square is irrational.  However, the argument as presented in the OP works precisely for squarefree integers greater than $1$.  For other numbers such as $12$, the result is true but the argument can't be used verbatim and must be adjusted.

Comment: @ErickWong ah, thanks for clearing that up! I was definitely beginning to get confused with the comments above!

Comment: @ErickWong You are right, my mistake. The key step is "$a^2$ must be divisible by $n$, but then so must $a$", which holds iff $n$ is square free. I had thought it holds iff $n$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: What about this: You arrived at having $4 b^2 = a^2$. This also means that $4 = \frac{4 b^2}{b^2} = 4$. This doesn't give you the result of $\sqrt{4}$ but it does not lead to a contradiction within the reasoning. Might this be a valid approach?

Comment: Side note: If you run the $\sqrt{2}$ proof for $\sqrt{4}$, arguing $4b^2=a^2\implies2\mid a^2\implies2\mid a$, then you end up finding $\sqrt{4}=2$.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just because $a^2$ is divisible by $4$, that doesn't mean $a$ is.

Answer (score 6):

Your error is stating that if $a^2$ is divisible by 4 so must $a$ be.  The fundimental theorem states if a *prime* $p $ divides $ab $ then $p $ must divide $a $ or $p$ must divide $b $.  That is true because $p $ is indivisable.

But if $p $ is composite it doesn't hold.  $p$ could equal  $jk $ and $j$ could divide $a $ and $k $ divide $b $.  Example: 3 divides 4 times 9 so 3 either divides 4 or 3 divides 9 because 3 is prime.  But 6 divides 4 times 9 but 6 neither divides 4 nor 9 but instead 3 divides 9 while 2 divides 4 so 6=2 times 3 divide 4 times 9.

So 4 divides $a^2$ means $2*2$ divides $a*a$ so 2 divides $a $ is all you can conclude with certainty.  ... because 4 is not prime.

Actually because 4 is not square free.  All of its prime factors must divide into $a$ but the square powers can be distributed among (and *are*) distributed among the square powers of $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Now If you want to prove that square root of a non perfect square is irrational.

Then you can do this what I wrote below as a proof.

Let $p$ is a non perfect square. We are required to prove $\sqrt{p}$ is irrational. Let $\sqrt{p}$

is rational and of the form $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a\;\;and\;\;b$ are coprime and $b\neq{0}$.
Now, we have

$$\sqrt{p}=\frac{a}{b}$$
By squaring both sides we have
$$p=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$$
$$\implies{a^2}=p{b^2}$$
We know that $a\;and\;b$ are coprime to each other and $g.c.d(a,b)=1$.
So we have $$ax+by=1$$ for some non zero integers $x$ and $y$.Then multiply $\sqrt{p}$ on both sides.Then we get
$$\sqrt{p}ax+\sqrt{p}by=\sqrt{p}$$See that $a=\sqrt{p}b$. So we have 
$$pbx+ay=\sqrt{p}$$
Now see that the L.H.S belongs to integer set whereas the R.H.S belongs to
$\mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Z}$.

Hence it is a contradiction.So $\sqrt{p}$ is irrational. May be it will help you.

Comment: It is a nice proof but it really doesn't do anything to answer the OP.  The question is not "how cause I prove this square root is irrational?" but "I know this proof is wrong somehow, but where is the error?"

Comment: That's because it doesn't mean if 4|a^2,then 4|a.A counter example is a=36.4|36 but 4 doesn't divide 6.

Comment: Yes, that was given in the other answers and comments.  I just find it odd that you submitted an answer to a different question than the one asked here.